# How to proper programmatically install Firebird ODBC Driver from c#?

Tags: c#, windows, firebird2.5

We have currently shipped with our ERP a simple utility that installs the Firebird Server 2.5 and the Firebird ODBC Driver programmatically.

- The server I install by executing some .bat files from the utility and it works perfectly on the port 3060.
- The ODBC I install by adding the odbc keys to the registry and then copy gds32.dll and odbcfb.dll files to the system32 folder.

We have been using this utility for more than a year now and the client instalation works ok, but sometimes there is an older version of the gds32.dll on the system32 folder being used by an older version of Firebird Server or an Interbase server and I can't simply update the gds32.dll because it would stop any other software that is using it.

Here's the driver instalation code:

```
class OdbcDriverHelper
{
    private static string ODBCINST_INI_REG_PATH = "SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBCINST.INI\\";
    private static string ODBCINST_INI_REG_PATH_DRIVERS = "SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBCINST.INI\\ODBC Drivers\\";
    private static string ODBCINST_INI_REG_PATH_6432 = "SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\ODBC\\ODBCINST.INI\\";

    public static void AddEntry(string nomeDriver, string caminhoDriver)
    {
        var driverKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(ODBCINST_INI_REG_PATH + nomeDriver);
        if (driverKey == null) throw new Exception(string.Format("ODBC Registry key for driver '{0}' does not exist", nomeDriver));

        driverKey.SetValue("APILevel", 1);
        driverKey.SetValue("ConnectFunctions", "YYY");
        driverKey.SetValue("Driver", caminhoDriver);
        driverKey.SetValue("DriverODBCVer", 03.51);
        driverKey.SetValue("FileExtns", "*.fdb,*.gdb");
        driverKey.SetValue("FileUsage", 0);
        driverKey.SetValue("Setup", caminhoDriver);
        driverKey.SetValue("SQLLevel", 1);
        driverKey.SetValue("UsageCount", 0x00000001);

        if (SystemInfo.is64BitOperatingSystem)
        {
            driverKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(ODBCINST_INI_REG_PATH_6432 + nomeDriver);
            if (driverKey == null) throw new Exception(string.Format("ODBC Registry key for driver on WIN6432NODE '{0}' does not exist", nomeDriver));

            driverKey.SetValue("APILevel", 1);
            driverKey.SetValue("ConnectFunctions", "YYY");
            driverKey.SetValue("Driver", caminhoDriver);
            driverKey.SetValue("DriverODBCVer", 03.51);
            driverKey.SetValue("FileExtns", "*.fdb,*.gdb");
            driverKey.SetValue("FileUsage", 0);
            driverKey.SetValue("Setup", caminhoDriver);
            driverKey.SetValue("SQLLevel", 1);
            driverKey.SetValue("UsageCount", 0x00000001);
        }
    }

    public static void InstallDriver()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(Constants.CAM_DRIVER_32))
                File.Copy("Firebird_32\\odbc\\OdbcFb.dll", Constants.CAM_DRIVER_32, true);

        if (!File.Exists(Constants.CAM_GDS32_32))
                File.Copy("Firebird_32\\odbc\\GDS32.dll", Constants.CAM_GDS32_32, true);

        AddEntry(Constants.ODBC_DRIVER_NAME, Constants.CAM_DRIVER_32);
    }
}
```

Note: This is not the original code, there are some more variables that I switched to hardcoded strings and a few try catch fallbacks that I didn't include just to keep it more clean.

Is there any other proper way of doing this without having to worry about these types of conflicts how would you do this programmatic installation more efficiently?